# hiding a column in a dynamic infragistics grid and updating header

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, infragistics

I have a infragistics grid that gets data when a dropdown is changed 
1- i want to hide the last column every time  the grid is loaded with data
2- i also want to update header according to data

problem 
I am trying

```
     protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EntityName.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string entity = "t_" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiveLeaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p_DataList_ByRegardingObject", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegardingObjectName", entity);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        this.EntityGrid.DataSource = dt;
        this.EntityGrid.Columns[6].Hidden = true;
```

its throwing null reference error and it doesnt seem to update column names each time it loads data.data is getting refreshed but not the column names.
here is my aspx

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem>Select Entity</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="EntityName"></asp:Label>
<ig:WebScriptManager ID="WebScriptManager1" runat="server"></ig:WebScriptManager>
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="EntityGrid" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="50%" StyleSetName="Claymation" >

    <Behaviors>
        <ig:Sorting>
        </ig:Sorting>

    </Behaviors>
    <ClientEvents Click="NavigateOnClick" />
</ig:WebDataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you tell me on which line throws the exception?

Comment: steve at this.entitygrid.columns[6].hidden=true; it throws the exception

Comment: the updating header is done by clearing columns. but for the hiding part i know the column is url for all entities but it may not be in the same column all the time is there away to hide it using this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `AutogenerateColumns` is `True` - grid column collection will be empty.  The trick is to get to the column via Grid Rows.

After grid is bound try this:

```
this.EntityGrid.Rows[0].Items[6].Column.Hidden = true;
```

Just make sure that grid has at least one row.

Comment: Yuriy Galanter it works fine most time but some places i get object not set to object instance errror. is this the right place to do it  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();                   
            da.Fill(dt);                       
            this.EntityGrid.DataSource = dt;
            this.EntityGrid.DataBind();
            this.EntityGrid.Rows[0].Items[6].Column.Hidden = true;

Comment: Can you verify whether Rows collection has no rows or Items collection has no items? You have to make sure that grid has data when this code is called. Also you may want to try moving this line into grid's `PreRender`event handler.

Comment: it there a way to hide using text ? like the column name is url

Comment: Using `this.EntityGrid.Rows[0].Items[]` collection you can loop thru it, checking `.Column.Header.Text` (or other column properties) and act accordingly